# Understanding part of a proof, to show commutatitivy of geometric mean for matrices

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Ando defined a matrix geometric mean, for two positive $n \times n$ matrices, as follows:

$$G(A,B) = B^{1/2}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})^{1/2}B^{1/2}$$

where all square roots are positive square roots. This definition has a commutativity property: $$G(A,B) = G(B,A)$$

A proof for this may look as follows:

$G(A,B) = G(B,A)$ is equivalent to $$
A^{-1/2}B^{1/2}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})^{1/2}B^{1/2}A^{-1/2} = (A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})^{1/2} \tag{1}$$
As positive matrices are equal if and only if their squares are equal, this is in turn equivalent to:

$$A^{-1/2}B^{1/2}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})^{1/2}  [B^{1/2}A^{-1}B^{1/2}] (B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})^{1/2} B^{1/2}A^{-1/2} = A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2} \tag{2}$$

Since the term in the square brackets is just $(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})^{-1}$, the left hand side of the expression above does indeed reduce to the right hand side.

My equation is, how exactly is $(1)$ equivalent to $(2)$?

I hope I did not make any typos, just incase, the proof can be found on page 2 of: http://www.personal.kent.edu/~bfeng/mercer1.pdf

Comment: The square of a matrix $M$ is the product of $M$ by itself: $M^2=MM$. With $M=A^{-1/2}B^{1/2}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})^{1/2}B^{1/2}A^{-1/2}$, just write $$MM=A^{-1/2}B^{1/2}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})^{1/2}B^{1/2}A^{-1/2}A^{-1/2}B^{1/2}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})^{1/2}B^{1/2}A^{-1/2}$$ and you're done (after writing $A^{-1/2}A^{-1/2}=A^{-1}$, which is something that must somehow be justified—yet it's very easy). This addresses how the left-hand side of (1) squares to the left-hand side of (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square of the LHS of $(1)$ is
$$
A^{-1/2}B^{1/2}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})^{1/2}B^{1/2}A^{-1/2}A^{-1/2}B^{1/2}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})^{1/2}B^{1/2}A^{-1/2}\\=A^{-1/2}B^{1/2}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})^{1/2}\left[B^{1/2}A^{-1/2}A^{-1/2}B^{1/2}\right](B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})^{1/2}B^{1/2}A^{-1/2}$$
Now the term in square brackets is the only issue. Note that since $A^{-1/2}A^{-1/2}=A^{-1}$, we can write it as $B^{1/2}A^{-1}B^{1/2}$. To see this is the inverse you just multiply by the thing you want it to be the inverse of and every term cancels.